# Получение данных об авторизованном пользователе Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, auth, платежи

Всем привет. Разрабатываю проект на Laravel 8. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: работаю с платежной системой для приема платежей. Когда пользователь совершает оплату, callback от платежной системы приходит на определенный адрес, потом обрабатывается и приходит методом POST на мой сайт. Затем отслеживаю это в web.php и передаю в контроллер. В контроллере мне нужно изменить данные о пользователе, который совершил оплату, но когда пытаюсь узнать о нем через `Auth::user()`, ничего не работает. Также пытался отследить id пользователя через `Auth::id()`, но тоже безрезультатно. Когда проверяю `Auth::check()`говорит о том, что пользователь неавторизован. Как можно решить эту проблему. Уже несколько дней думаю над этим вопросом. Буду очень благодарен тому, кто сможет помочь.

web.php:

```
Route::post('/payment', [RateController::class, 'payment'])->name('payment');
```

RateController:

```
public function payment(Request $request) {
    if($request->input('status') == 'done') {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->rate = $request->input('rate');
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

Прием callback:

```
<?php
    $str = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $object = json_decode($str, true);
    $url = 'https://findinvestor.me/payment';
    $params = array(
        'rate' => 'bronze',
        'status' => $object['status'],
    );
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'content' => http_build_query($params)
        )
    )));
?>
```

Comment: И где в callback хоть что-то, через что вы отслеживаете пользователя? Нельзя просто взять и передать в другой код вызов, надеясь что там будет что-то что вам нужно ... Прикрепите данные в $object, наверняка там есть что-нибудь для этого.

Answer (score 0):

Маршрут 'payment' находится за пределами middleware auth. Вероятнее всего.
Если так, то фасад  Auth вам ничего и не предоставит о пользователе.
Сперва получите сведения о пользователе в ответе от платежного сервиса, потом попытайтесь его найти в своей базе.
Попытайтесь авторизоваться с ним, если для этого достаточно будет данных. После всего это фасад Auth “начнёт работать”.
Если у вас весь «жизненный цикл» оплаты происходит в моменте, то надо поместить маршрут в middleware('auth').